# Module object is not callable. i dont know why

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import os
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands, check

def check_if_user_has_premium(ctx):
    with open("premium_users.json") as f:
        premium_users_list = json.load(f)
        if ctx.author.id not in premium_users_list:
            return False

    return True

@bot.command()
@check(check_if_user_has_premium)
async def apremiumcommand(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello premium user!")

@apremiumcommand.error
async def apremiumcommand_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
            await ctx.send("Sorry, but you are not a premium user!")
    else:
        raise error


bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

I am getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 269, in 
@check(check_if_user_has_premium)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `@commands.check(...)`, instead of `@check(...)`?

Comment: @AbhishekPratapSingh No, `json.load` is for files where `json.loads` is for strings. same as `json.dump`/`json.dumps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#checks), You should have done

`@commands.check(f)`
and not `@check(f)`

You also need to remove the `, check` from the import line since that function only exists under the module `discord.ext.commands`

Comment: Please mark it as solved if that helped you :D